# What is best for DHCP server?

Tags: dhcp

I have a network with three AP's, a server and a router.
where should i set up the DHCP server? On the router or on the server?

Comment: Respectfully, it's not a bad question, and putting the DHCP services on the server is wrong.  Why should the network stop serving users (atleast new users / dhcp clients) just because the server is out?  In other words, it's not really opinion, it's right/wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the router will be more convenient for you. 
Because you may use your server in other needs.

Comment: Why would that interfer with running a DHCP server?

Comment: The less processes, the more server's processor will work efficiently

Comment: This answer is correct because if the server fails, it brings down the network with it (for new dhcp clients).  In other words, putting the DHCP services on the server is wrong.